# How to register data points?

Tags: prometheus

I am very new to Prometheus. What I want is record the total number of times my specific code is called.

Based on my understanding, I should somehow send data in my code to Prometheus and Prometheus would handle and record the data point. I have looked through the Prometheus API list at https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/, but I couldn't find any way to register my custom data point.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

Your code should record your user-defined metric and publish this (and any other metrics) on an HTTP endpoint. Then, you configure the Prometheus server to periodically "scrape" your endpoint, read the metric(s) and record them.

Prometheus uses a text-based "exposition format" that could reasonably easily code for yourself but, the Prometheus client SDKs are preferred. Which language(s) are you using? These SDKs usually handle running the HTTP server that exposes your metrics for scraping by Prometheus.

References:

- O'Reilly [Exposition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/prometheus-up/9781492034131/ch04.html)
- Exporters (like your code) expose metrics ([Writing Exporters](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/))
- [Client Libraries](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/) can be used to expose metrics (i.e. by your code)
- [Prometheus: Getting Started](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/)

If you are familiar with containers, I encourage you to run Prometheus in a [container](https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/prometheus). You can provide the container with a configuration that will scrape your code's metrics.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So does this mean "There isn't a HTTP-URL based method to publish my data, but the data structure is too complexed that I have to use a third party library to do this", am I correct?

Comment: Prometheus primarily uses so-called "pull-based" system for metrics collection. The Prometheus server (as a client) makes HTTP requests to the things (e.g. your code) being monitored. These are expected to run a HTTP server (also by convention a `/metrics` endpoint) which Prometheus scrapes expecting the metrics to be published using its text-based (exposition) format. Push (gateway) is also supported by discouraged.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand that I have to create my HTTP endpoint and Prometheus will periodically "send requests" to that endpoint to collect data. However I am still confused how does Prometheus know my endpoint exists? For example, if I start an HTTP server with port say 1234 definitely Prometheus would't lop through every single possible port to check if an endpoint exists right?

Comment: Also, if my code is a process that will execute and finish in a finite time, how should I handle the endpoint?

Comment: I recommend you read the documentation. All these questions are answered there. You will need to provide Prometheus with a configuration file that includes the list of endpoints you want it to scrape.

Comment: Processes that terminate aren't good candidates for scraping. In part because, by the time Prometheus tries to scrape them for metrics, they may no longer exist. It may be that your requirements are better placed to use push metrics but I encourage you to read the docs and learn more about these mechanisms and whether Prometheus is, in fact, suitable for your needs. Good luck!